# Webpack on visual studio

Tags: javascript, css, .net, visual-studio, webpack

I keep getting the following error when I try to run webpack task runner in visual studio 2022.

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module './Webpack/webpack.[object Object].js'
```

Following is my folder structure and I have tried using npm install -g webpack.
No css or js files are missing.

[image]

Comment: Has anyone else faced this issue, I think its a bug in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using npm link?

```
npm link webpack
```

This should link the globally installed webpack to your project.

Alternatively, try

```
npm install webpack
```

without the -g to install it locally.

Comment: Yes I have tried it all.